# How to get the time Stamp of a file from the folder

Tags: java, date, filesystems

suppose I have a file called xyz.csv in /home/netsys/Documents/Backup/lxr100_trunk_Aug22nd/lxr100/build/web/WebPages/reports.... report folder.. how to get the time of a file... in java

Comment: Which time you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

[edit] The [lastModified()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified--)-Method in the File-Class seems to be what you are looking for?

[Original answer]
Have you tried the solution suggested in http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/java-get-file-timestamp.shtml